# Servlet Exception( java.lang.StackOverflowError ) for inserting a value from table to other one

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i am developing a servlet app that show the table in jsp and than insert a value of the that table in other table (inserting a id from table to another table) as i checked with debugger there is no problem to read a value from first table and  insert it to scound table  but when i clicked on insert button after some moment i have this error(java.lang.StackOverflowError) also when i check mysql table i see, i have the value more than the time that i insert it like a infinite loop.about the table that i am reading a data i can say (name of the table :class,id( type:int(primary),null:no,default:none,Extra:AUTO_INCREMENT),name(type:
varchar,null:yes,default:current_timestamp)) and the table i am inserting a value is(table name test,id(type:int(index),null:yes,default:null))

i want to say it again that beside of the error i have more insertion that i click on jsp in sql table(like 100 times more)

```html
// servlet class
public class add_course extends HttpServlet {
 private dbutil dbutil;
 @Resource(name="jdbc/web_student_tracker")
 private DataSource dataSource;
 @Override
 public void init() throws ServletException {
  //dbutil= new dbutil(dataSource);
  super.init();
  try {
   dbutil=new dbutil(dataSource);
  }
  catch(Exception exc) {
  throw new ServletException(exc);
  }
 }
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
//  List<student> student;
//  try {
//   student = dbutil.getcourse();
//   request.setAttribute("select",student);
//   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/course.jsp");
//  dispatcher.forward(request,response);
//  } catch (Exception e) {   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//   e.printStackTrace();
//  }
  try {
   String thecommand=request.getParameter("command");
   if(thecommand==null) {
    thecommand="LIST";
   }
   switch(thecommand) {
   case"LIST":
    listcourse(request,response);
    break;
   case"insert":
    insertcourse(request,response);
    break;
   }
  }
  catch(Exception exc) {
   throw new ServletException(exc);
  }
  
 
 }
 private void insertcourse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
  int courseid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("courseid"));
  student thestudent=new student(courseid);
  dbutil.insetcourse(thestudent);
  insertcourse(request,response);
   

 }
 private void listcourse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
  List<student> student=dbutil.getcourse();
 request.setAttribute("select",student);
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/course.jsp");
 dispatcher.forward(request,response);
 }

}
```

```html
// db class
public List <student> getcourse() throws Exception{
 List<student> course=new ArrayList<>();
 Connection myConn = null;
 Statement myStmt = null;
 ResultSet myRs = null;
 try {
  
  myConn=dataSource.getConnection();
  String sql="select id from class";
  myStmt=myConn.createStatement();
  myRs=myStmt.executeQuery(sql);
  while (myRs.next()) {
 int id = myRs.getInt("id");
 student tempstudent = new student(id);

    course.add(tempstudent);
 }
 return course;
}
 finally {
  // close JDBC objects
  close(myConn, myStmt, myRs);
 }  
}

public void insetcourse(student thestudent)throws SQLException  {
 Connection myConn = null;
 PreparedStatement myStmt=null;
 /////////
 try {
  myConn = dataSource.getConnection();
  String sql="insert into test"+"(id)"+"value(?)";
  myStmt=myConn.prepareStatement(sql);

  myStmt.setInt(1,thestudent.getId());
  
  myStmt.execute();
  
 }
 finally {
  close(myConn,myStmt,null);
 }
}
}
```

```html
//jsp page 
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<c:forEach var="tempstudent" items="${select}">
<c:url var="insert" value="add_course">
  <c:param name="command" value="insert"/>
    <c:param name="courseid" value="${tempstudent.id}"/>
   </c:url> 
<tr>
<td>${tempstudent.id}</td>
<td> 
  <a href="${insert}" 
       onclick="if (!(confirm('Are you sure you want to insert this student?'))) return false"> 
      
      insert</a>  
       </td> 
</tr>

</c:forEach>




</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you calling `insertcourse` recursively ???

Comment: this is how did i learn when i have more than one method  in my servlet i should call it like that , do you think this cause the problem for inserting?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. you are not providing any breaking logic, are you trying to insert one record or multiple records ?

Comment: i am try to insert  multiple records but for example when i insert 3  and than 5 instead of having 3 and 5 in the table , i have 100s or more of them on the table.can you please tell me how can i prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to insert multiple records in a table why not use a `for loop` instead of recursive method.

```
private void insertcourse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // Assuming you are getting multiple courseid in your request, 
    Object[] courseid = request.getParameter("courseid");
    for(Object obj : courseid)
    {
          student thestudent=new student(courseid);
           dbutil.insetcourse(thestudent);
     }
    request.setAttribute("message", "Records loaded successfully");
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/course.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request,response);


}
```

when the insertion is done, you dipatch result to forntend, so that user would be notified,

if you want to insert only one record just call `insert` onlyonce.

but looking at your jsp code, you are generating `insert` hyper link for every record, hence you will be inserting only one record at a time, in that case you can follow below code.

```
  int courseid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("courseid"));
  student thestudent=new student(courseid);
  dbutil.insetcourse(thestudent);
  request.setAttribute("message", "Records loaded successfully");
  RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/course.jsp");
  dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

Comment: thank you!, it works now . can you tell me what was my mistake exactly?

Comment: You are calling the `insert` method within itself, but you have not provided any condition which breaks the infinite loop, this will cause keep loading the same class into the stack at jvm level, since its infinite loop, stack got full and resulting in stackoverflow error.